# grub rescue: grub not installed

Tags: dual-boot

I tried to install beside my windows 7. It didn't work. After installing it could not find the root directory and I got some other error messages... I just wanted my computer to be faster again so instead I decided to reinstall windows from recovery disk. It formatted the disk and installed windows again.

The hard-disk has msdos structure now and the ubuntu partition is empty

When I start up the computer grab is starting up an I get a grab rescue problem, but grab is no longer installed. How can I boot directly into windows?

- i can boot Ubuntu from an usb stick but I'm not able to install it anymore. I just want windows to work again...

I'm hoping for advice...

Linda

Answer (score 1):

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Or from Ubuntu you can directly install the lilo boot loader which works just like Windows boot loader.
Restore basic windows boot loader - universe enabled if error on lilo not found
Simply open Synaptic and Settings > Repositories and tick the box against the Universe repo in the Ubuntu Software tab. Close that window and click on reload before installing lilo with Synaptic or command line.

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

May show error messages about the rest of lilo missing, ignore, we just want MBR with bootloader to boot partition with boot flag (Windows).

Or just use a Windows RepairCD or flash drive and run fixMBR.

Answer (score 0):

I ASSUME you just want to reinstall the Win 7 loader (aka chainloader).

You can write a Win 7 recovery DVD from any Win 7 machine. Boot from recovery DVD, choose to recover win loader from the graphic menu, or choose to enter command line and execute *bootrec /fixmbr*, then *bootrec /fixboot*.